# Output prints several times

Tags: python, pyqt4, beautifulsoup, qwebview

Code below works fine, beside one thing: Desired output prints few times =)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from random import choice
from urllib import urlretrieve
from urllib2 import *
import sys
import os


# Settings for browser
class MyBrowser(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        # Specifies whether images are automatically loaded in web pages.
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)

    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15"



class Name_Creater(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setPage(MyBrowser())
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.grab_first_name)
        self.frame = self.page().mainFrame()

    def grab_first_name(self):
        html = unicode(self.frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
        soup = bs(html)
        for name in soup.findAll('li', text=True):
            print name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    url_first_names = QUrl("http://www.genealogyroadtrip.com/Census/male_names_1.htm")
    br = Name_Creater()
    br.load(url_first_names)
    br.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why do you believe that it shouldn't?

Comment: for name in soup.findAll('li', text=True):
            print name   why can this not print multiple times?

Comment: I believe I did something wrong, and want my output to be printed only once

Comment: Whats the output that prints out several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are connecting to the `loadFinished` signal of the `QWebView`, which will be emitted once *for each page* that is loaded. So if there are multiple frames, there will be multiple `loadFinished` signals emitted.

The solution is to connect to the `loadFinished` signal of the [mainFrame](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#mainFrame):

```
self.setPage(MyBrowser())
self.frame = self.page().mainFrame()
self.frame.loadFinished.connect(self.grab_first_name)
```